# php_value auto_prepend_file value cached

Tags: php, apache

I used to have a `php_value auto_prepend_file ...` line in my `.htaccess`, and unless I include a new one, the old value is still used.

The old value points to a file which no longer exists, and so I get

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/_redacted_/sessions/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I've had to create an empty file to include, and that works, but I'd love to understand how this is happening.

Comment: htaccess files are not cached. have a look in your vhost, the line might be in there too

Comment: I didn't think so, yet that's what appears to be happening. I have checked the vhost. I've restarted apache, I've created new vhosts, I've restarted the VM.

Comment: I have the same problem , and i didn't found any solution yet

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3 places where this value can reside:

1. `php.ini` (and files included from there, if your distro does it)
2. Apache's configuration files (these require restarting of Apache and override whatever you have in `php.ini`)
3. `.htaccess` files. Strictly speaking, there might be several of them on different levels of file-system hierarchy (these are applied without restart and override whatever you have in other places)

p.s. You can use `phpinfo()` call to see the list of ini-files